# get ALL posts AND post the user liked MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, request

I'm triying to get ALL posts and a variable "liked" next to the post to check if the user liked it or not.

I have three table with theses :

**-posts**

```
+----+---------+---------+
| id | user_id |   text  |
+----+---------+---------+
```

**-votes**

```
+----+-----------+---------+---------+
| id | type_vote | user_id | post_id |
+----+-----------+---------+---------+
```

**-users**

```
+---------+---------+
| id_user | etc..   |
+---------+---------+
```

I check the others answers but it don't solve my problem. Also I tried this code :

```
SELECT id, text,
            IF('$uid' IN (SELECT id FROM votes WHERE user_id='$uid'), 1, 0) AS liked
            FROM posts
            INNER JOIN users
            ON users.id_user = posts.user_id
            WHERE posts.user_id = '$uid' OR posts.user_id 
        ORDER BY posts.created_at desc
```

But it returns only posts created by user and the liked variable doesn't work..

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance !

**EDIT :**

I managed to get the id of the votes next to the appropriate post, how to transform it in 0 if NULL and 1 if id exists ?

```
SELECT p.*,(SELECT id from votes where user_id = '$uid' AND post_id = p.id) as liked from posts p
```

I get a result like :

```
    +----+------+---------+---------------+
    | id | text | user_id |liked          |
    +----+------+---------+-----+---------+
    | 1  | blab | 5476zef |NULL OR post_id|
    +----+------+---------+---------------+
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Some non-ANSI SQL there...)

Comment: Hi, i'm using mysql

Comment: Add some sample table data, and the expected result. (As well formatted text.)

Comment: I edit my question !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about the relationship between "likes" and "votes".  However, if you want all posts and additional information, then a `left join` or correlated subquery comes to mind.

I think this may be what you want:

```
select p.*
       (exists (select 1
                from votes v
                where v.post_id = p.id and v.user_id = $uid
               )
       ) as user_flag
from p;
```

There may also be some condition on `type_vote`, but your question doesn't explain how that field is used.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Yes i forgot, but my votes table stock likes AND dislikes, so yes i need also conditions but if i get the thing, i'll do it myself.

Thanks you for your code, i think i know how to build my request, but one things, i don't manage to get the value in my json response
Value of user_flag is always "0"

Comment: @Efbi . . . That would suggests that the given user has always voted (in some way) on each post.

Comment: Yeah i tried to vote, in the databse it's ok, when i do the sql query too it's ok, but the json response don't show the value ! I edited my post

Answer (score 1):

SELECT products.title,isfav.isFavourite
FROM
products
LEFT JOIN isfav
ON products.product_id = isfav.product_id
and isfav.user_id=2
ORDER BY
products.added_date

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an if-condition:

```
IF(liked IS NULL,0,1)
```

You can either add a column or replace liked with your expression.